# FILE pointer is expired without rhyme or reason

Tags: c, file

I have this problem after I add some socket connection codes **after** following codes. What could be a reason when `fp` is ok, pointing some memory address, while reading the data (line 4), but when debugger(gdb) reaches the `if` block, `fp` pointer is just pointing 0x0.

```
#define CHANNELS_PER_IOM   25

...

int OldValues[CHANNELS_PER_IOM];
FILE * fp;
FILE * fp_t;
int buff;
int i;

fp = fopen("/windcom/tmp/dout_values", "r");
fp_t = fopen("/windcom/tmp/dout_values.tmp", "w");
i = 0;

while(fp && fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &buff) == 1) // fp is pointing some address here.
{
    i++;
    OldValues[i-1] = buff;
    //printf("%d %d \n", OldValues[i-1], buff);
}
if(!fp) //fp is pointing 0x0 here.
{
    for(i=0; i<CHANNELS_PER_IOM; i++)
    {
        OldValues[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is `OldValues` defined? You have probably not large enough and unfortunately the `fp` is getting overwritten inadvertently.

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
while(i < CHANNELS_PER_IOM &&
      fp &&
      fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &OldValues[i++]) == 1) // fp is pointing some address here.
{
    // Empty
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Put

And after

```
fp = fopen("/windcom/tmp/dout_values", "r");
```

put

```
if (!fp) printf("Unable to open file\n");
```

and this will check if the file is actually opened.

Comment: What is the value of `CHANNELS_PER_IOM` and `i` at the `if` statement?

Comment: I agree with Ed. You most probably write out of the OldValues array's bounds. This way you invoke undefined behaviour. At the very least you overwrite fp, fp_t or some other variable. At the worst you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @EdHeal, its value is just 25, not big but ... is it really enough to overwrite to fp?

Comment: I try Edit 2, the file is opened. There is no err msg.

Comment: @EnesUnal - If you have done the two edits I cannot see anything wrong. Perhaps you are not supplying the vital bit of code.

Comment: I will change the general structure just for this C's ibnetorluk.